# Passing (function) user-specified column name to dplyr do()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

#### Original question

Can anyone explain to me why unquote does not work in the following?

I want to pass on a (function) user-specified column name in a call to `do` in version 0.7.4 of `dplyr`. This does seem somewhat less awkward than the older standard evaluation approach using `do_`. A basic (successful) example *ignoring the fact that using `do` here is very unnecessary* would be something like:

```
sum_with_do <- function(D, x, ...) {
    x <- rlang::ensym(x)
    gr <- quos(...)

    D %>%
        group_by(!!! gr) %>%
        do(data.frame(y=sum(.[[quo_name(x)]])))
}

D <- data.frame(group=c('A','A','B'), response=c(1,2,3))
sum_with_do(D, response, group)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   group [2]
  group     y
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A        3.
2 B        3.
```

The `rlang::` is unnecessary as of dplyr 0.7.5 which now exports `ensym`. I have included lionel's suggestion regarding using `ensym` here rather than `enquo`, as the former guarantees that the value of `x` is a symbol (not an expression).

Unquoting not useful here (e.g. other [dplyr examples](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#Unquoting)), replacing `quo_name(x)` with `!! x` in the above produces the following error:

```
Error in ~response : object 'response' not found
```

#### Explanation

As per the accepted response, the underlying reason is that `do` does not evaluate the expression in the same environment that other dplyr functions (e.g. `mutate`) use.

I did not find this to be abundantly clear from either the documentation or the source code (e.g. compare the source for [`mutate` and `do` for data.frames](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/dataframe.R) and follow Alice down the rabbit hole if you wish), but essentially - and this is probably nothing new to most;

- `do` evaluates expressions in an environment whose parent is the calling environment, and attaches the current group (slice) of the data.frame to the symbol `.`, and;
- other dplyr functions 'more or less' evaluate the expressions in the environment of the data.frame with parent being the calling environment.

See also [Advanced R. 22. Evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html) for a description in terms of 'data masking'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of regular `do()` semantics where there is no data masking apart from `.`:

```
do(df, data.frame(y = sum(.$response)))
#>   y
#> 1 6

do(df, data.frame(y = sum(.[[response]])))
#> Error: object 'response' not found
```

So you just need to capture the bare column name as a string and there is no need to unquote since there is no data masking:

```
sum_with_do <- function(df, x, ...) {
  # ensym() guarantees that `x` is a simple column name and not a
  # complex expression:
  x <- as.character(ensym(x))

  df %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    do(data.frame(y = sum(.[[x]])))
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by data masking.

Comment: That's when you can refer to the data directly. We call it data masking because the data columns have precedence (mask) over user-defined objects. This is similar to how package objects can mask each other and how objects in the global workspace can mask package objects.

Comment: Do you mean that the expression passed to a function like `mutate()` is evaluated in the environment of the data.frame, whereas the expression passed to `do()` is evaluated in a different environment?

Comment: Right, the `do()` environment only contains the pronoun `.`